# MTConnect Agent Errors when installing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mtconnect

I am trying to install MTConnect on Ubuntu and when running the conan export commands I get the following errors

This command produces the error below:

```
conan export conan/mqtt_cpp
```

The error:

```
======== Exporting recipe to the cache ========
ERROR: Error loading conanfile at 
'/home/edge/edgeApp/mtconnect/cppagent/conan/mqtt_cpp/conanfile.py': Unable to load 
conanfile in /home/edge/edgeApp/mtconnect/cppagent/conan/mqtt_cpp/conanfile.py
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/edge/edgeApp/mtconnect/cppagent/conan/mqtt_cpp/conanfile.py", line 1, 
in <module>
    from conans import ConanFile, tools
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConanFile' from 'conans' 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/conans/__init__.py)
```

I get the same error for:

```
conan export conan/mruby
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I confirmed the files are available by running

```
nano /home/edge/edgeApp/mtconnect/cppagent/conan/mqtt_cpp/conanfile.py
```

Python 3.10, all of the other dependencies are installed

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Edit: I have also tried various different file permissions for those specific files and the entire directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be the version of Conan. I had version 2.04 (the current version).

I uninstalled conan

```
pip uninstall conan
```

And installed version 1.59

```
pip3 install conan==1.59
```

I basically picked versions at random. It seemed anything > 2.0 didn't work and gave me cryptic errors, and anything under 1.59 showed errors saying I needed to update. So I uninstalled and re-installed incrementing a version each time (starting at 1.53) until it worked. Not the most efficient method, but it did work.